# inductively defined group statements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If A is a set, and $B_{1}, B_{2}\subseteq A$ subsets of $A$.

Also, $f_{1}:A\rightarrow A$
and $f_{2}:A\rightarrow A$ we will mark: $F1={f1} , F2={f2}$

How do I prove the following:

1. $X_{B1\cap B2,F1}\subseteq X_{B1,F1}\cap X_{B2,F1}$
2. $X_{B1,F1\cup  F2}\subseteq X_{B1,F1}\cup X_{B1,F2}$

When $X_{B,F}$ is the closure of B under F which is  inductively defined .

I'm not sure I'm getting the hang of it.

Comment: It's totally unclear what do you mean by "When $X_{B,F}$ is the closure of $B$ under $F$ which is inductively defined". I think this is the reason why nobody has answered yet.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It sounds as if you’ve defined $X_{B,F}$ in the following way (or something very similar).

> Let $X_{B,F}^{(0)}=B$. Given $X_{B,F}^{(n)}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, let $X_{B,F}^{(n+1)}=X_{B,F}^{(n)}\cup F\left[X_{B,F}^{(n)}\right]$. Then set $X_{B,F}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}X_{B,F}^{(n)}$.

If so, prove by induction on $n$ that for each $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $X_{B_1\cap B_2,F}^{(n)}\subseteq X_{B_1,F}^{(n)}$; the first result follows immediately from this.

Alternatively, show that

$$X_{B,F}=\bigcap\{S\subseteq A:B\subseteq S\text{ and }F[S]\subseteq S\}\;;$$

this also makes it easy to prove the first result.

If I understand your notation correctly, the second result isn’t true. Let

$$f_1:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto\begin{cases}
n,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
n+2,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;,
\end{cases}$$

and let

$$f_2:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n=0\\
0,&\text{if }n=1\\
n,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Let $B=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. Then $X_{B,F_1}=B$ and $X_{B,F_2}=B\cup\{1\}$, so $X_{B,F_1}\cup X_{B,F_2}=B\cup\{1\}$, but $X_{B,F_1\cup F_2}=\Bbb N$: $1\in X_{B,F_1\cup F_2}^{(1)}$, so $3\in X_{B,F_1\cup F_2}^{(2)}$, and in general $2n-1\in X_{B,F_1\cup F_2}^{(n)}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.